# How to inject routes to external angular module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

I am using angular 4.0.2. I would like to create a reusable layout module for my apps that would consist of some html layout with navbar, sidebar etc. Template contains router-outlet but I don't know how to have routes injected from outside.

Here is what I am trying:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [Layout, Sidebar, Navbar]
})
export class LayoutModule {
    static forRoot(routes): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LayoutModule,
            providers: [provideRoutes(routes)]
        }
    }
}
```

then in application.module I would import module providing (application specific) routes:

```
LayoutModule.forRoot(PagesRoutes)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. My routes are not registered and I get 404.

However, when I change it to:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [Layout, Sidebar, Navbar],
    providers: [provideRoutes(PagesRoutes)]

})
export class LayoutModule {
}
```

then routes work fine, except they are not injected as a dependency.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround that solves the problem.

On my client app I have a thin wrapper around external LayoutModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        LayoutModule
    ],
    providers: [provideRoutes(PagesRoutes)]

})
export class LayoutWrapperModule {
}
```

Injecting routes this way works.